# Azure DevOps - custom build templates are gone

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've created build templates and manuals for the teams how to setup pipelines in VSTS.

In the new design our custom build templates are gone.

How to bring them back?

---

**Old design**
[image]

---

**New design**
[image]

Comment: Disable the preview-feature "New YAML pipeline creation experience" for now. i haven't seen about how to add custom yaml-templates yet

Comment: Hope it will be fixed